# Align Header with Text/Type Area in KOMA but let Page Number bleed into Margin

Tags: header-footer, margins, koma-script, page-numbering

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}%
    \clearscrheadfoot%clear default
    \lehead{\llap{\pagemark\enskip\rule[-2ex]{1.5pt}{4.5ex}}\enskip\headmark}%
    \rohead{\headmark\enskip\rlap{\rule[-2ex]{1.5pt}{4.5ex}\enskip\pagemark}}%
\usepackage{lipsum}     
    \begin{document}
        \chapter{First Chapter}
        \lipsum
        \section{The first Section}
        \lipsum
        \newpage
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}
        \newpage
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}
    \end{document}
```

What I am trying to do is this:

[image]

And surprisingly, it works, taking `\rlap` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6287/bleed-text-into-the-page-margins). There have been others questions like this, but not often with KOMA, like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227943/header-style-with-page-number-under-bleeded-rule).

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432909/header-in-scrbook-with-vertical-and-horizontal-lines) comes quite close, but they use the entire `headwidth=textwithmarginpar`, an area/width much too large for me.

I simply want the vertical `\rule` to be aligned along the text, and the page number -- be it one, two, three or even four digit -- to bleed into the margin freely.

While that is achieved, my questions are:

1. it seems rather hacky. Especially defining the `\rule` twice manually (even positioning it manually) makes me think there is a smarter solution here.
2. are there caveats to using the rule? I guess it takes away vertical space in an unplanned manner; is that okay typographically? I don't want to mess with the carefully crafted defaults. For example, the text now seems to sit quite 'high up'; I thought about pushing it down.
3. simply forcing the page number into the margin seems hacky, too. I guess KOMA is not aware this is happening, which might cause incompatibilities or crashes I am not aware of yet?

Comment: It seems perfectly acceptable to me: it's highly predictable where this will go, and the page geometry is fixed. I wouldn't be too precious about it if the effect seems desirable to you. Personally, I think it's a fussy bit of typographical decoration: but that's just a personal aesthetic choice.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I now used a `newcommand` for the `rule`, so it looks quite cleaned up now. You're definitely right that it looks quite fuzzy, fidgety and maybe too alternative. But I like it once the fully-fledged, two-sided output is in front of you.

Comment: You could use `\smash` in the definition for the rule: `\newcommand*\headvrule{\smash{\rule[-2ex]{1.5pt}{4.5ex}}}`. `\smash` hides the height and the depth of its argument.